# How to permanently disable swap file?

Tags: swap, 17.04

Ubuntu 17.04 introduces a swap file to replace swap partitions.  However, I would prefer not to have any disk-based swap space at all, so I would like to know how to turn the swap file off.

*Clarification:* I need a way to turn the swap file off *permanently*.  AFAIK, the swapoff command only disables it temporarily.

*Clarification 2:* I do not want swapping disabled completely, as I am using zram as my swap.  I only want the *swap file* disabled.

My question *specifically* deals with the **swap file**, while the answers to the other questions deal with either turning off the swap partition, or they deal with turning off all swap.  I do not want either, I just want the swap file turned off.

Comment: That question's answer only shows how to disable a swap partition temporarily.  Editing my question.

Comment: @Alban Yeah, I double-checked through that file.  All of the answers deal with either temporarily disabling swapping, or disabling the swap partition.  Nothing about swap files.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus There's an answer about disabling it in /etc/fstab by Sohail xIN3N

Comment: Also worth reading: https://askubuntu.com/questions/103242/is-it-safe-to-turn-swap-off-permanently and https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question closed. Both questions have answers that explain how to remove swap entries from `/etc/fstab` which is what you need to do to disable a particular swap space permanently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how to disable the swap file in Ubuntu 17.04

To turn off the swapfile. Run the following command:

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
```

Now disable the swap file in `/etc/fstab`. I'm using Vim.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Your `/etc/fstab` file should have a '#' in front of '/swapfile'

[image]

After this is done. save your changes and exit.

Now we're going to physically remove the swap file. run the following command:

```
sudo rm -f /swapfile
```

and voila! For the changes to take full effect, reboot the system, and use the 'free' command to confirm there is no available space for swap.

Comment: Apparently, my system never had the swap file enabled in the first place.  Probably because I installed 17.04 by upgrading from 16.10, rather than installing it fresh.

Comment: WRONG.
1) I already ran swapoff -a (but it still was remounted at boot)
2) there is no entry in fstab

see my answer for the solution

Comment: I also had removed the entry from sysctl.conf, which nobody has in their answer here, dont forget that.. (both swappiness and cache_pressure).

I should stress, if you dont want to cause your self a nightmare, dont forget to remove (or comment) the fstab entry.

@Zibri i'm not seeing your answer either.

Answer (score 1):

Any swap file or partition that starts at boot is in the `/etc/fstab` file. If you remove the line associated with that swap file in the `fstab` it won't start up again after a reboot.

Comment: perhaps it would be wiser to comment out the line than to remove it entirely